# Conditional Formatting Rule for running sum less than or equal to a number in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to apply conditional formatting or another formula on a multiple range of cells to determine if the combined sum in a range of cells is equal to or less than a value in a single cell?

The first attachment is a screenshot of the forecast report I am looking to apply this formula to. The highlighted green/red cells is what I am looking for the formula to do automatically for all items.

Screenshot of how I am looking for formula to work:
[image: Screenshot of how I am looking for formula to work]

The second attachment is the current conditional formatting rule I have but it is not working properly and I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Screenshot of current formula I have but it is wrong:
[image: Screenshot of current formula I have but it is wrong]

For example, I need to know how far out the current Quantity on Hand for a given part covers demand for.

Ex.) Item SC688 (row 2)-- Qty on hand is 13,012. This only covers demand for the months of June and July. I want to use a formula to automatically highlight the months current on hand qty covers through (06/2023 and 07/2023) and highlight in red the remaining months (08/2023 - 06/2024) that current stock wouldn't cover. Can this be done with conditional formatting or is there another formula I need to use?

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: ,,,, it's as simple as U are trying (2nd Screen Shot) ,,,, since the screen shot data/formula is not readable,,, so that I can't find the reason ,, please share the formula what U have used so far ,,, then I'll try to fix it ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a minor error in the formula which is causing the formatting to applied  not based on what you want.

`=$E$2<SUM($H2:H2)` (specifically the `$E$2`) means an absolute cell reference to always (for all rows) makes the comparison based on the *Qty On Hand* of the first row. In order to allow the cell reference (to compare to) to be a relative reference (changed to the *Qty On Hand* of the current row) you'd need to have it as `$E2` with the `2` being a relative reference.

So use for the red:

```
=$E2<SUM($H2:H2)
```

And for the green (also improving here adding the equals, that if it matches exactly, it should still be green and not remain white):

```
=$E2>=SUM($H2:H2)
```

[image]

Comment: I would try to avoid two mutually exclusive conditional formats. This makes Excel work out both cases, where only one is needed. In other words, give all the cells a background colour of green*, and just apply the condition that turns them red (or the other way round). Also consider the edge case where the total = Qty On Hand and make sure the colour is what you would want to see, or maybe add a condition for this as "amber" (yellow) to indicate that this month's order is fulfillable, but there will be zero stock left for next month.
*Also, make the green a lot lighter so the red "pops".

Comment: @Yisroel Tech thanks for your help it looks like this worked!!